# AVAudioPlayer multiple stop problem in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avaudioplayer, viewdidload

I have piano keyboard.When I press the key I want the previous key not to be interrupted before calling *func pianoKeyUp*.So I created another player in *pianoKeyDown*.

**The problem is:** When simultaneously press the key created AudioPlayers is not deleted or simultaneous deletion occurs and gives an error about the missing element in AudioPlayers array and app crashes.What is the better way to play piano sound multiple?

```
var audioPlayers = [KeyAudio]()
```

---

There is a struct for each piano key that init in `ViewDidLoad()` in *for key in* cycle

```
     struct KeyAudio {
            let audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer
            var playersArray : [AVAudioPlayer]

    init(audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer) {
        self.audioPlayer = audioPlayer

        var array =  [AVAudioPlayer]()
        array.append(audioPlayer)
        self.playersArray = array
      }
    }
```

`ViewDidLoad()`

Prepare each player to play and append to `audioPlayers` array with *init of KeyAudio*

```
    for key in 1...61 {
                do {
                    let pianoSoundURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "\(key).wav", ofType: nil)!)
                    let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: pianoSoundURL, fileTypeHint: nil)
                    audioPlayer.volume = 0.1
                    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                    let player = KeyAudio(audioPlayer: audioPlayer) // init
                    self.audioPlayers.append(player)

                } catch(let error) {
                    print(error)
                }
```

And I have functions from *custom piano view*

**First** - **keyDown** - triggered when piano key pressed

If `player.isPlaying` I create another `AudioPlayer` and append it to common array of each note

```
    func pianoKeyDown(_ keyNumber: UInt8) {

        let number = Int(keyNumber)
        audioPlayers[number].audioPlayer.setVolume(0, fadeDuration: 0.05)

        if audioPlayers[number].audioPlayer.isPlaying {

            let pianoSoundURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "\(number+1).wav", ofType: nil)!)
            guard let duplicatePlayer = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: pianoSoundURL) else { return }
            audioPlayers[number].playersArray.append(duplicatePlayer)
            duplicatePlayer.prepareToPlay()
            duplicatePlayer.currentTime = 0
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                duplicatePlayer.play()
                duplicatePlayer.setVolume(0.8, fadeDuration: 0.05)
            }

        } else {
            guard let firstTimePlayer = audioPlayers[number].playersArray.first else { return }
            firstTimePlayer.currentTime = 0
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                firstTimePlayer.play()
                firstTimePlayer.setVolume(0.8, fadeDuration: 0.05)
            }
        }
    }
```

And **second** - **keyUp** - when finger is released I stop `AudioPlayer` created by first tap, then check if another `AudioPlayer` created by next tap
 and **there is the problem**

```
    func pianoKeyUp(_ keyNumber: UInt8) {


        let number = Int(keyNumber)
        if let firstPlayer = audioPlayers[number].playersArray.first, firstPlayer.isPlaying {
            audioPlayers[number].audioPlayer.setVolume(0, fadeDuration: 0.75)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.75, execute: {
                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    if self.audioPlayers[number].audioPlayer.isPlaying {
                        self.audioPlayers[number].audioPlayer.stop()
                    }
                }
            })

        }


        let isIndexValid = audioPlayers[number].playersArray.indices.contains(1)
        if isIndexValid, audioPlayers[number].playersArray[1].isPlaying {
            audioPlayers[number].playersArray[1].setVolume(0, fadeDuration: 0.75)
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.75, execute: {
                if self.audioPlayers[number].playersArray.indices.contains(1) {
                            self.audioPlayers[number].playersArray[1].stop()
                            self.audioPlayers[number].playersArray.remove(at: 1)

                }
            })
```